# How to create own table in Bookdown and reference it within the text?

Tags: r-markdown, bookdown

I am currently writing my thesis in RMarkdown using the template Oxforddown (which is ultimately based on bookdown). I have been reading the documentation but I confess I am lost. I am trying to create a table that contains an overview of the experimental conditions and items I used in my empirical study, so it is not data that I can load into R and then use the kable function on. However, I do not understand how I could generate such a table. Generating RMarkdown tables outside code chunks seems to work, but then the captions and referencing are very different than the rest of the captions used so far, which I usually set up within code chunks. Example below:

`{r pilot-short7, echo=FALSE, fig.scap="Pilot 2: ....", out.width="65%", message=FALSE, fig.pos='H', fig.align = 'center'}`

When I am trying to include RMarkdown tables inside a code chunks, things go wrong. What would my options be?

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prepared a markdown template for you.

Here I made a table with **flextable** library.

But you can use another, which you like, f.e.: **kableExtra**, **gt** etc.

As you can see, you should put  `\label{tab:caption}` and after refer in the text by `\ref{tab:caption}`.

````
---
title: "Hello World"
header-includes:
- \usepackage{caption}

output:
  pdf_document: 
       latex_engine: xelatex
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r, include = FALSE}
library(flextable)
library(dplyr)

table2 <- flextable(mtcars[1:5, 1:6]) 
   
```
This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

\begin{table}[hbtp]
\captionof{table}{Text of the caption.}
\label{tab:caption}
`r table2`
\end{table}

Table \ref{tab:caption} is the baddest table in the World
````

[image]

Comment: thank you very much for your help! I have tried implementing this in my chapter, but it does not seem to work.  I will keep trying though! Thank you!

Comment: @Ana-MariaPlesca Where is the problem, can you give a chunk of your code?

Comment: just wanted to let you know that your template worked after all. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Ana-MariaPlesca Have a nice work ;)